# Java multithreading using .join(); Can you assign the idle thread to help still running threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple method which is multithreaded as follows:

```
int processors=Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
detectors[] theCores = new detectors[processors];

    for(int i = 0; i < processors; i++){
    theCores[i] = new detectors();
    theCores[i].start();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < processors; i++){
    try{ // Waits for completion of all cores
    theCores[i].join();}
    catch(InterruptedException IntExp) {} 
    }
```

Using .join(); means that finished threads will pause until completion of all threads. Because all threads are not identical in speed, some will finish before others and there is sometimes quite a significant gap between the time it takes for the fastest thread to finish the method compared to the slowest thread. Is there any way to assign the cores that are finished and waiting to help out the remaining threads in their execution?

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Fork/Join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) in Java 7

> The fork/join framework is distinct because it uses a work-stealing
>   algorithm. Worker threads that run out of things to do can steal tasks
>   from other threads that are still busy.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the OS do this for you: instead of scheduling as many threads as processors/cores are available, start slightly more threads. If one thread is finished, the OS will provide the remaining threads with all the remaining CPU power. Depending on the type of work a load factor of 2 (threads = 2 * cores) can be a good choice. This should give you 100% CPU load for most of the time, whereas with a number of threads lower than the number of cores, the CPU load often is less then that, especially if the threads are memory or I/O intensive. In this case you should increase the factor even more.

Answer (score 0):

"to help out the remaining threads in their execution", the work each thread does should be split in lesser parts (usually named tasks). Otherwise it is impossible to parallelize monolitic job coded as `run()` method. All the tasks are put in a common queue and each worker thread then takes next task from it. Such a construction is called `thread pool` and Java runtime library has several implementations for it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

In case tasks has mutual data dependencies, more sophisticated facilities should be used: fork-join pool (mentioned by endriu_l), [CompletableFuture.html](http://download.java.net/lambda/b88/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) from Java8, dataflow and actor libraries (they are numerous and easy to find, I only refer [df4j2](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j2/tree/master/df4j-core) of mine).